# Suddenly Firebase function doesn't read req.body in one function (but works in another)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have 2 Firebase functions that both have the same code, using npm request and cors to get the req.body in the start like this:

```
exports.state1 = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // [END trigger]
  // [START sendError]
  // Forbidding PUT requests.
  if (req.method === 'PUT' || req.method === 'GET') {
    return res.status(403).send('Forbidden!');
  }
  // [END sendError]

  // [START usingMiddleware]
  // Enable CORS using the `cors` express middleware.
  return cors(req, res, () => {
    // [END usingMiddleware]
    // Reading date format from URL query parameter.
    // [START readQueryParam]
    let format = req.query.format;
    // [END readQueryParam]
    // Reading date format from request body query parameter
    if (!format) {
      // [START readBodyParam]
      format = req.body.format;
      // [END readBodyParam]
    }
const frompage1 = req.body;


console.log('Sending Formatted data:', frompage1);

var authtoken = frompage1.authtoken.toString();

//some code

    }); //end cors

    }; //end function
```

Then I read the authtoken and proceed.

In both functions the output of "sending formatted data" works:

```
Sending Formatted data: { Authorization: '444444******',
  subscriberID: 1860******150,
  dialogID: '2020-05-15 13:26:35.8',
  state: 'state2',
  ButtonOrder: 2 }
```

In one function, it can also isolate authtoken with this code:

```
var authtoken = frompage1.authtoken.toString();
```

But the same exact code stopped working in a similar function 1 hour ago, though it had been working before that.

Does anyone have any idea why I get this error now?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined at cors
```

Comment: Why do you expect `frompage1.authtoken` to contain a value?  Your debug output suggests there is no such property on `frompage1`, and it's not clear from your question why it should exist.

Comment: From my code you can see, it outputs frompage1 in console.log which comes from req.body, then it doesn't output authcode.

Comment: I can see the output.  It's not clear **why** you expect there to be an authtoken property.  We can't see how you're making the request to include that value.

Comment: I expect an authtoken property because it exists in the req.body as is shown by the console.log -- is that what you mean?

Comment: I don't see it.  I see "Authorization" which is a different string than "authtoken".